# Power on/off using Appium commands

Tags: webdriver, appium, python-appium

I am trying to Power on/off a device using appium. I modified Webdriver.py in Appium python client. I added a function and command for power off. Its not working. Can anyone help me with Appium commands for power on/off. PS - I can not use adb commands

Answer (score 1):

`adb shell reboot -p` power off device

`adb reboot -p` restart the device

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested what function you added, because Appium server **does not support** device power on/off out of box, the only way you can do it is to use `adb` directly